# Code Behind only UserControl Inheritance not showing up in Designer

Tags: wpf

I was wondering if it was possible to permit the designer to render a class that Inherit UserControl but without any xaml, I've done that because I have common code on some page but they don't look the same at all. It work perfectly fine but the Designer cannot render it because I call it without xaml (I think, but then if I make one it say there is already something defined at the root so it don't work)

I have Menu_Type that inherit UserControl, and my menus are defined

```
<Menu_Type x:Class="MyNameSpace.Main_Menu
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Grid>//the content of my menu, that can completely differ</Grid>
</MenuType>

namespace ComonLibrary.Views {
public class Menu_Type : UserControl {
    protected MainWindow window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow.Content;
    protected MenuItem? selected;
    public int subMenuLevel;
    protected void SelectionMenuItemx(MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (selected != null) selected.Background = Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
        menuItem.Background = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        selected = menuItem;
    }
    public void NewContent(MenuItem item, Type type) {
        if (selected == item) return;
        if (item != null) SelectionMenuItemx(item);
        for (int i = subMenuLevel; i <= 4; i++) if (window.FindName("PnMenu" + i) is ContentControl c) c.Content = null;//Reset Menu de plus bas niveau si on reste au niveau du sender
        window.PnCentral.Content = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
    public void NewMenu(MenuItem item, Type type) {
        if (selected == item) return;
        SelectionMenuItemx(item);
        window.PnCentral.Content = null; //Reset PnCentral si on descend d'un niveau
        for (int i = subMenuLevel + 1; i <= 4; i++) if (window.FindName("PnMenu" + i) is ContentControl cM) cM.Content = null;//Reset Menu de plus bas niveau que celui que l'on gère
        if (window.FindName("PnMenu" + subMenuLevel) is ContentControl c) {
            c.Content = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            if (c.Content is Menu_Type m) m.subMenuLevel = subMenuLevel + 1;
        }
    }
    protected void Exit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        window.PnCentral.Content = null;
        for (int i = subMenuLevel - 1; i <= 4; i++) if (window.FindName("PnMenu" + i) is ContentControl c) c.Content = null;
    }
    protected void Quit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Note that Main_Menu is Menu_Principal (It's just translated to put it here)
[image: Menu_Type usage in Menu_Principal]

Answer (score 0):

**OBVIOUS issue is that your xaml start with `Menu_Type` and has an incorrect unbalanced closing tag of `MenuType`**

You mean something like this?  Just create a class (.cs file) and extend it.  In the example below I am creating a custom control with 2 dependency properties. This has no xaml its just code.

[image]

You don't have to create new dependency properties, you could override properties if you want, just make sure to call base code so that proper behavior persists.

**UPDATE:** per your comment.  The reason that it does not like your `Menu_Type` is because the namespace you have in the xaml does not match the class definition.

Your xaml says:  `MyNameSpace.Main_Menu` but the class name is a completely different namespace. It should be `ComonLibrary.Views.Menu_Type`

Here is a example, I am creating a custom control inheriting from UserControl:

[image]

Here is code:

[image]

One other OBVIOUS issue is that your xaml start with `Menu_Type` and has an incorrect unbalanced closing tag of `MenuType`

Comment: I've edited to add my code behind class, it's the full code but when I do the first one (the one in xaml) it say that the type Menu_Type doesnt exist / not found, but it work fine after playing it's just the designer that doesnt work.
I know there is thing to desactivate sometime otherwise the designer play it and design runtime doesnt work but I don't know if there is something that it doesnt support here ?

Comment: It does not correspond because Main_Menu inherit Menu_Type and it's Main_Menu who has the xaml of the design

Comment: i dont see a Main menu type

Comment: Sorry if you didnt understood me because my english is lacking, its usercontrol > menu_type > Main_menu, all my menu has the function from menu_type but not the same design so i made different xaml that take the code from menu_type (thats inheriting no ?)

Comment: i explained all that you need to do to inherit... not sure what I am missing from your explanation.

Comment: you don't put what class you are extending in xaml you simply define the class that supports the xaml

Comment: @VirgilNauleau, look at my latest update... you have an unbalanced open and closing xaml tag

Comment: @T McKeown , since i need to import the type it start with <lib:Menu_Type and end with </lib:Menu_Type> And if i do <UserControl instead, because it's not the same class has the one i inherit it say cs error CS0263 , i'm adding a screen so you understand how im using the menu_type. Also thank you for taking your time helping me